# Javascript maximum call stack size exceeded error when accessing Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm working on a project using socket.io. When I click a button, I'm supposed to be added to a specific server that is stored in a Map. When I click the button, the call gets sent to the server, but then I get a maximum call stack size exceeded error. I narrowed it down to my `sendToServer` function.

client js file

```
var socket;
let id;
let state = "MENU";
var menu, serverlist, game;
let servers;
var isMobile;

var dispX, dispY;

var touch = false;

function setup() {
  declare();
  createCanvas(dispX, dispY);
  menu = new Menu();
  game = new Game();
  serverlist = new List();
  console.log("Hello World!");
  socket = io.connect("https://hidy.glitch.me:443");
  socket.emit("start", "Hello Server!");
  id = socket.emit('getid');

  socket.on("get", function(data) {
    if (state == "SERVERLIST") {
      servers = new Map(Object.entries(data));
      serverlist.loopServers();
    }
  });

  socket.on("heartbeat", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}

function draw() {
  if (state == "GAME") {
    game.show();
  } else if (state == "SERVERLIST") {
    serverlist.show();
  } else {
    menu.show();
  }
  updateTouch();
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (state == "MENU") {
    menu.evalClick();
  }
  if (state == "SERVERLIST") {
    serverlist.evalClick();
  }
}

function touchStarted(){
  touch = true;
  if (isMobile) {
    if (state == "MENU") {
      menu.evalClick();
    }
    if (state == "SERVERLIST") {
      serverlist.evalClick();
    }
  }
}

function updateTouch() {
  if (touch == true) {

  }
}

function touchEnded() {
  touch = false;
}

function emitToServer(func, msg) {
  socket.emit(func, msg);
}

function emitKeyValue(key, value) {
  socket.emit('create', key, value);
}

function sendToServer(sid) {
  console.log('s');
  socket.emit('addtoserver', sid, socket);
  console.log('h');
}

function declare() {
  isMobile = (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
  if (!isMobile) {
    dispX = displayWidth / 2;
    dispY = displayHeight / 2;
  } else {
    dispX = displayHeight;
    dispY = displayWidth - 109;
  }
}

function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

Server Side:
create function

```
    socket.on('create', function(id) {
      console.log("Creating server " + id);
      servers.set(id, new GameServer(id));
    });
```

addToServer function

```
    socket.on('addtoserver', function(sid, socket) {
      console.log('Adding socket to ' + servers.get(sid)); // I don't even get this message printed to console
      servers.get(sid).addClient(socket);
    });
```

Full class where the error is:

```
class List {

  constructor() {
    this.back = new Button(50, 25, 100, 50, "Menu", 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
    this.clear = new Button(width - 50, 25, 100, 50, "Clear", 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
    this.add = new Button(width / 2, 25, 200, 50, "Create Game", 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
    this.list = [];
    this.loopServers();
    this.array = new ARList(width / 2, 100, 100, 25, this.list, 20, 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
  }

  show() {
    background(83, 28, 179);
    this.back.show();
    this.clear.show();
    this.add.show();
    this.array.show();
  }

  loopServers() {
    this.list = [];
    if (servers != null) {
      this.list = Array.from(servers.keys());
      this.array = new ARList(width / 2, 100, 200, 25, this.list, 20, 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
    }
  }

  evalClick() {
    if (this.back.clicked()) {
      state = "MENU";
    }
    if (this.clear.clicked()) {
      emitToServer('clear');
      this.loopServers();
    }
    if (this.add.clicked()) {
      var sid = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
      emitToServer('create', sid);
      sendToServer(sid);
      game = emitToServer('getserver', sid);
      state = "GAME";
    }
    if (this.array.clicked() != null) {
      sendToServer(this.array.clicked().getText());
    }
  }

}
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.JsDelivr.net/gh/bmoren/p5.collide2D/p5.collide2d.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="gray">
    <script src="client.js"></script>
    <script src="/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="/game.js"></script>
    <script src="/server.js"></script>
    <script src="/list.js"></script>
    <script src="/button.js"></script>
    <script src="/label.js"></script>
    <script src="/arlist.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
// Using express: http://expressjs.com/
var express = require('express');
const GameServer = require('./gameserver');

// Create the app
var app = express();
var servers = new Map();

// Set up the server
// process.env.PORT is related to deploying on heroku
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || window.location, listen);

// This call back just tells us that the server has started
function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
}

// You need to add the folders that you want to access to here
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('public/game'));
app.use(express.static('public/menu'));
app.use(express.static('public/serverlist'));
app.use(express.static('public/server'));
app.use(express.static('utils'));

// WebSocket Portion
// WebSockets work with the HTTP server
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  // The heartbeat is sent to all clients every X seconds
  // We can use the heartbeat as a way to sync data among users
  // We will need 2 heartbeats, the first one from the client to the server with their data packet (we will need a way of shortening the data to a small packet to avoid loss-of-data)
  //                            the second one from the server to all clients with the data packets (we will need some way of parsing the received data)
  setInterval(heartbeat, 1000);
  setInterval(serv, 50);

  function heartbeat() {
    io.sockets.emit('heartbeat', 'Hello');
  }

  function serv() {
    io.sockets.emit('get', Array.from(servers.entries()).reduce((main, [key, value]) => ({...main, [key]: value}), {}));
  }

// Sends the user to index.html on connect
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/view.html");
});

// Register a callback function to run when we have an individual connection
// This is run for each individual user that connects
io.sockets.on('connection',
  // We are given a websocket object in our function
  function(socket) {

    console.log("We have a new client: " + socket.id);

    socket.on('getid', function() { return socket.id });

    socket.on('start',
      function(data) {
        console.log('Received data ' + data)
      }
    );

    socket.on('update',
      function(data) {
        console.log('Updating ' + data);
      }
    );

    socket.on('create', function(id) {
      console.log('3');
      console.log("Creating server " + id);
      servers.set(id, new GameServer(id));
      console.log('d');
    });

    socket.on('getserver', function(id) {
      console.log('2');
      return servers.get(id);
    });

    socket.on('addtoserver', function(sid, socket) {
      console.log('1');
      console.log('Adding socket to ' + servers.get(sid));
      servers.get(sid).addClient(socket);
    });

    socket.on('clear', function() {
      servers = new Map();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log("Client has disconnected");
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: to clarify, is the error on the client or on the server?

Comment: its because your code making  infinite recursion on client-side

Comment: @JatinParmar - you can see that in the code posted?

Comment: @Bravo no , but in javascript, this kind of error occurs due to infinite recursion

Comment: @JatinParmar where is the infinite recursion? The button click is only fired once so I don't know how there could be infinite recursion.

Comment: @MrShawn please provide some more code with HTML and all socket event listeners

Comment: @MrShawn use a debugger or add some more `console.log` calls to determine exactly where the code stops, and the error occurs. If you do a `console.log` and it outputs to the console repeatedly, that's where the infinite recursion is.

Comment: so, the error is on the server side, correct? Because you say "here is where the error is" just before some server side code - so the error is being displayed where you rune nodejs?

Comment: @Bravo The error is being shown in the console on the client-side. I can't seem to find the infinite recursion through console.log messages.

Comment: oh ... so why do you declare "Here is where the error is! addToServer function" in the middle of your two server side snippets of code? Clearly the error is not there, it's in the client

Comment: I added a bunch of console.log messages, none of them sent more than once.

Comment: @Bravo Thats where I assumed the error was because I couldn't find any recursion on the client.

Comment: right - so the error is in the client, so that piece of code probably doesn't even get called at all ... have you tried console.log's in the client code leading up to the problem to see how far into `if (this.add.clicked()) {` you get before the error occurs?

Comment: The last place a console.log message gets sent is right before `socket.emit('addtoserver', sid, socket);` in the sendToServer() function.

Comment: @Bravo last place a message is sent client side is right before this line: `socket.emit('addtoserver', sid, socket);`

Comment: post whole project, why so few code posted?

Comment: @sonnenhaft I've added the full classes / files to the post